# Papervision3d bitmap effect

Tags: bitmap, effect, papervision3d

I am programming Panorama like google streetview. But how can I do bitmap effect when the image changing? In streetview it is blur and some flor effect.

How can I do effects?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Viewport Layers](http://blog.zupko.info/?p=129).

Comment: Yeah I know. But i want to do bitmap effect that is used in streetview. At streetview when you clicked road,the image like zoomming and other image is coming.